# how to edit a large amount of json objects?

Tags: json, node.js

```
[
    [{
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20170906
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20170921
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 2
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20170929
        },
        " metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171004
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171010
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": " /",
            "date": 20171018
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171020
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171030
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linke din.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171112
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171123
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180106
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensi ons": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180119
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180120
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180124
        },
        "metrics": {
            " visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180126
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180209
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180212
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180216
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180217
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "p agePath": "/",
            "date": 20180223
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "linkedin.com",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20180308
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": "lnkd.in",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171007
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }, {
        "dimensions": {
            "source": " lnkd.in",
            "pagePath": "/",
            "date": 20171120
        },
        "metrics": {
            "visits": 1
        }
    }]
]
```

i get 10k+ lines of json like this, from multiple sources and pages as you can see in the made-up example above how it looks like.

the result i would like to have is like this :

```
{
    "dimensions": {
        "source": "linkedin.com",
        "pagePath": "/"
    },
    "metrics": [{
        "visits": 1,
        "date": 20171205
    }, {
        "visits": 10,
        "date": 20171205
    }, {
        "visits": 8,
        "date": 20171205
    }, {
        "visits": 6,
        "date": 20171205
    }, {
        "visits": 5,
        "date": 20171205
    }, {
        "visits": 3,
        "date": 20171205
    }]
}
```

what is the best way to achieve this ? i looked at a lot of examples but somehow i still dont get it. my problem is that when i use something like JSON.Parse() to convert 1 object. i get multiple objects with 1 array of 1 metric(visit+date) instead of 1 object with 1 array of multiple metrics(visit+date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like, the other poster suggested (I've tweaked the answer a little bit), You can try the `Array.filter` like this,

```
var filtered_result = jsonObj.filter(function (item, index) {
  return item[index].dimensions.source == 'linkedin.com'
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> You can use Array.filter method

```
 var result =  jsonObject.filter(item => {
   return item.dimensions.source == 'linkedin.com' //any condtion you can give
 })
```